# Can I keep the MacBook Pro Retina's power-cord plugged in at all time?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I disconnect my MacBook Pro’s power cord when the battery is fully charged?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12271/should-i-disconnect-my-macbook-pros-power-cord-when-the-battery-is-fully-charge)

I'm wondering if it's reasonable to use a MacBook Pro Retina as a desktop replacement with power-cord plugged in all the time? Or does the battery suffers from this kind of use?

Comment: Since your question seems to be just about wether or not is it OK to keep the power adapter plugged in, I feel it's been already asked and answered [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12271/should-i-disconnect-my-macbook-pros-power-cord-when-the-battery-is-fully-charge) and [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66512/how-often-should-i-remove-the-charger-from-my-rmbp).

Comment: -1 for duplicate posting as @garry already pointed out

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, Apple does not recommend leaving your portable plugged in all the time, as for a **lithium-based** battery, it's important to keep the electrons in it moving occasionally. MacBook / Pro, though, are designed to deliver up to **1000** full charge and discharge cycles before it reaches **80%** of its original capacity.

A charge cycle means using all of the battery’s power, but that doesn’t necessarily mean a single charge. For instance, you could listen to your iPod for a few hours one day, using half its power, and then recharge it fully. If you did the same thing the next day, it would count as one charge cycle, not two, so you may take several days to complete a cycle. Each time you complete a charge cycle, it diminishes battery capacity slightly.

Since 2009-2010 laptops carry a technology called **Adaptive Charging** which basically is a chip within the battery that talks to its cells monitoring everything from charge level to temperature. The chip relays this information to the computer, which uses an advanced algorithm to determine the optimal charging current. Adaptive Charging reduces the wear and tear on the battery giving it a lifespan of up to 5 years.

**So**, I'll actually won't worry that much about the battery. Just try not to keep it plugged all the time, and remember to do a full charge cycle at least once per month.

Comment: Your answer is useful, but pretty vague. Apple recommends doing one battery cycle per month, so does that mean it's best to leave it connected the rest of the time?

Comment: Lots of citation required here!