# Should I care too much about battery cycles?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I bought a MacBook Pro 13 inch 2017 two days ago and it’s been already 4 cycles

Is it something that I have to care about?

Comment: You also need to answer the questions, how much have you used your MBP and how many times have you recharged it (and when)?

Comment: 10-12 hours per day on the past two days, and I charged it 3 times

Comment: There's your 4 cycles.  Once from the factory for the initial charge and the three that you did. See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/233751/119271

Comment: Thank you very much! at what percentage should I start charging? I saw people saying 20% and some say it is not important, what do you think?

Comment: 10 years ago, this would be an issue.  With LIBs and the advent of undercharge protection circuitry (you don't actually completely drain the battery; there's still a charge), this is no longer a problem.  Charge it when it's convenient/necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It may have been through a handful of cycles in the factory for testing (unless you checked that it was at zero cycles when you unboxed it?). I'd just keep an eye on it over the next couple of weeks and make sure the number doesn't keep increasing too fast.

Comment: I didn’t check that but I’ve used the laptop for 12 hours a day on the past two days

Comment: @GhassanSaeed Running off battery, or plugged into power?

Comment: Running off battery

Comment: I believe you are right about the factory, but how frequently should the cycles increase? I mean what’s the moderate rate of increasing if I use my MacBook 8-10 hours a day?

Comment: I have another question, should I use the laptop as it plugged in? Even if it’s 100%? Is it good for the battery? Because I’m currently always home when using it

Comment: I'd chip in and recommend you to go through this discussion: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70639/can-i-keep-the-macbook-pro-retinas-power-cord-plugged-in-at-all-time

Answer (score 0):

The charge holding capacity on MacBook's battery drops after they have consumed a certain number of cycles.

From the Apple Support document, [About Mac notebook batteries](https://support.apple.com/kb/ht204054):

> Batteries are expected to function for a certain number of cycles. This number represents the sum of total and partial discharge cycles throughout the life of the battery.

Refer to the Apple Support document, [Determine battery cycle count for Mac notebooks](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201585) to determine the battery cycle count.

> Batteries have a limited amount of charge cycles before they're considered to be consumed. Once consumed, a replacement battery is recommended. You can use your battery after it reaches its maximum cycle count, but you might notice a reduction in your battery life.

A dedicated Apple website, [Batteries - Maximizing Performance](https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/) contains tips to get the best out of your MacBook's battery.

It's clear that it's a good idea to prolong the safe count charge cycles. It is okay to use the MacBook plugged in all the time, just like a desktop. However, you shouldn't go for weeks without discharging.

I personally make sure to completely drain the battery on my MacBook Pro once a month.

A couple more links for you to refer:

- [Can I keep the MacBook Pro Retina's power-cord plugged in at all time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70639/can-i-keep-the-macbook-pro-retinas-power-cord-plugged-in-at-all-time)
- [Can I keep my MacBook pro plugged in all times while working on it?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3818265)

Comment: Apple are no longer recommending monthly discharge cycles for new laptops, and if you read the link you provided you'll see that it is not in fact mentioned.