# Should my MacBook be on charge most of the time?

Tags: battery

For optimal battery health, should I charge my Mac most of the time, apart from letting it run through a full battery discharge once a month?

Comment: Not much has changed since this answer was provided: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66512/how-often-should-i-remove-the-charger-from-my-rmbp also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89613/ and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212504/